# fatal error: asm/atomic.h: No such file or directory on debian10 os

Tags: c, debian

My system is debian 10. I want to implement atomic operations, but I find that there are no header files and API functions for atomic operations. What's the matter? Isn't atomic operation a kernel level function? Why not?

test_atomic.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>

int main(void)
{
     printf("test atomic!\n");
     return 0;
}
```

compile error:

```
# gcc test_atomic.c
test_atomic.c:2:10: fatal error: asm/atomic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/atomic.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

man atomic API error:

```
# man atomic_add
No manual entry for atomic_add
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using atomic operations you need to use `#include <stdatomic.h>`.

Comment: thanks, The header file is ok. Do you have any suggestions on how to find the API?

Comment: @guoyanzhang https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic